# The return of alarm of thread "Non-deferrable Alarm :0" websphere application server while stopping the WebSphere Server

Tags: sas, websphere

I am trying to stop the WebSphere server, but I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
[1/20/19 18:57:19:312 AST] 00000028 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1021I: An attempt is made to stop the SASServer8 server.
[1/20/19 18:57:24:453 AST] 00000004 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: ibmasyncrsp
[1/20/19 18:58:08:863 AST] 0000002c AlarmThreadMo W   UTLS0008W: The return of alarm thread "Non-deferrable Alarm : 0" (00000004) to the alarm thread pool has been delayed for 49440 milliseconds. This may be preventing normal alarm function within the application server. The alarm listener stack trace is as follows: 
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.stop(WebContainerImpl.java:679)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stop(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1151)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStop(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1324)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.stop(DeployedModuleImpl.java:646)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.stop(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1098)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:922)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stop(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:875)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.stopComponent(ContainerHelper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.stopComponents(ContainerHelper.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.stopComponents(ContainerImpl.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.stop(ContainerImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.stop(ApplicationServerImpl.java:257)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.stopComponent(ContainerHelper.java:475)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.stopComponents(ContainerHelper.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.stopComponents(ContainerImpl.java:650)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.stop(ContainerImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.stop(ServerImpl.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerCollaborator$ShutdownHook$1.run(ServerCollaborator.java:738)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5305)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerCollaborator$ShutdownHook.run(ServerCollaborator.java:728)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerCollaborator$StopAction.alarm(ServerCollaborator.java:692)
    at com.ibm.ejs.util.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656).
```

Had anyone faced this issue before and found a solution?
Or is there any workaround for it?